# Deferred Queue in Jquery with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, deferred

I'm trying to access a DB using phonegap sqlite and want to create a deferred queue.

How i'm trying to access the db is as follows

```
for(i=0,max=elem.length;i<max;i++)
{
   functiontoAccessDB(i);
}
```

I want to make sure that only 1 call is made to the db every time and all others calls are deferred till 1st one returns a response.Any insights ?

Answer (score 0):

The SQLitePlugin uses a callback pattern as opposed to Deferreds. You will need to wrap it in order to use Deferreds.

Something like this might help:

```
var function functionToAccessDBForPromise = function(i){
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var successCallback = function(){
        d.resolve(args);
    };
    var failCallback = function(){
        d.reject(args);
    };
    functiontoAccessDBWithCallbacks(i,successCallback,failCallback)
    return d.promise();
};
```

`functionToAccessDBForPromise` will return a promise object that you can use for queuing.

Comment: This will simplify to `functiontoAccessDBWithCallbacks(i,d.resolve,d.reject);`. `successCallback` and `failCallback` can disappear.